# Java 8 ThreadPoolExecutor not Executing when using PDFBOX Classes

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a need to take these PDF files which are thousands of pages and extract the data into a database. Unfortunately, their data cannot be extracted as text, I have to extract the pages as PNG files, then run them through OCR in order to get the text. No big deal, just another day ...

Problem is, each page takes several seconds to convert into PNG, so I thought I would take that part of the code and toss it into a separate Thread, then just execute a bunch of them through a thread pool and see if that would speed things up a little...

I mean I have this 16 core MacBook Pro with 32 gigs of RAM, may as well put it to use once in a while, right?

I've worked extensively with threads, but I can't remember a time where I have ever used a ThreadPool because I never have a need to run a whole bunch of threads at the same time ... till now.

So here is my code that defines the thread pool and adds tasks:

```
public void extractRawPDF() {
    String             sourceFileName = EmployeeA;
    String             tempFileName   = "EmployeeA_";
    File               sourceFile     = new File(path, sourceFileName);
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor       = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    try {
        PDDocument source = PDDocument.load(sourceFile);
        for (int page = 0; page < source.getNumberOfPages(); page++) {
            int           pageNumber            = page + 1;
            String        pageNumberString      = (pageNumber < 10) ? "0" + pageNumber : (String.valueOf(pageNumber));
            String        tempImageFileFullPath = C.tempPath + "/" + tempFileName + pageNumberString + ".png";
            ExtractImages extract               = new ExtractImages("Task" + page, page, tempImageFileFullPath, path, sourceFileName);
            executor.execute(extract);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (executor.getActiveCount() > 0) {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            String line = "Tasks:" + executor.getTaskCount() + " Waiting:" + executor.getActiveCount() + " Completed:" + executor.getCompletedTaskCount();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

And here is the class that is the Task being sent into pool:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;
import org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio.ImageIOUtil;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExtractImages implements Runnable {

    public ExtractImages(String name, final int pageNumber, final String tempImageFileFullPath, String path, String sourceFileName) {
        this.pageNumber            = pageNumber;
        this.tempImageFileFullPath = tempImageFileFullPath;
        this.name                  = name;
        this.path                  = path;
        this.sourceFileName        = sourceFileName;
    }

    private final int    pageNumber;
    private final String tempImageFileFullPath;
    private final String name;
    private final String path;
    private final String sourceFileName;

    public String getName() {return name;}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            File          sourceFile = new File(path, sourceFileName);
            PDDocument    source     = PDDocument.load(sourceFile);
            PDFRenderer   renderer   = new PDFRenderer(source);
            BufferedImage image      = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageNumber, 300, ImageType.RGB);
            ImageIOUtil.writeImage(image, tempImageFileFullPath, 300);
            System.out.print("Image: " + tempImageFileFullPath + " SAVED!");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the output looks like from the extractPDFPages() method:

```
 Tasks:77 Waiting:20 Completed:0
 Tasks:77 Waiting:20 Completed:0
 Tasks:77 Waiting:20 Completed:0
 Tasks:77 Waiting:20 Completed:0
 Tasks:77 Waiting:20 Completed:0
 etc.
```

Changing the config of the pool, like adding more threads or messing with the core and max threads only affects the numbers that I see in the output above ... and that's it!

[And I based my implementation mostly on this link](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/java-thread-pool-executor-example/), but I've read several tutorials and Googled and I just can't seem to figure this out.

What is happening, is that the tasks are getting into the pool, but they aren't running. And if I run them without a ThreadPool, they will run just fine. For example, if I just create new instances of ExtractImages and throw each one into a new thread and start it ... the threads do in fact execute and do what I expect them to do. But it's chaos like that - like it won't create all of the png files that would have been extracted from the document, I assume because the threads were just walking all over each other and had too many simultaneous writes happening in the file system and it had to be shut down ... which is lame...

I've tried adding tasks to the pool in various ways, such as a Task method, a Thread method, I've tried adding the task via lambda in the execute statement. Nothing seems to make any difference at all.

Any ideas? What extremely simple thing am I completely missing here? Cause I know it's gonna be something stupid simple that I am incapable of seeing at the moment for some reason .... this seems like it should be a relatively simple thing to do in Java ...

EDIT: I changed the extractRawPDF method and the ExtractImages class because of the comment made by @Turing85 ... now, the thread itself would be doing all instantiations of the File class and the related PDF classes, but the threads are still not running. Perhaps these PDF classes are not ThreadPool friendly?

Also, here is my POM file in case anyone is interested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <!-- necessary for intellij to function -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <groupId>com.simtech</groupId>
    <artifactId>TuttleText</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>technology.tabula</groupId>
            <artifactId>tabula</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.asprise.ocr</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-ocr-api</artifactId>
            <version>15.3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.simtechdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>Switcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a shared resource that is not accessible or blocked. My suggestion is that the handle for the file is still open (in the main thread) and thus the worker threads are waiting for the handle to be released.

Comment: Your while cycle is infinitive.  It should be `while(executor.getActiveCount() > 0)`

Comment: @PetrAleksandrov Yes, I noticed that after I posted this ... I fixed it.

Comment: @Turing85 - OK, I'll look into it ... I'll have the thread start the file handle and see how that works.

Comment: @Turing85 So I eliminated the use of the File class altogether, so that the only things being passed into the Task are Strings and the PDF Renderer and it's still not running. It must have something to do with the PDF Renderer itself... still playing with it.

Comment: @Turing85 I updated the post with the new method and class. Still not working... very puzzling indeed.